# Upload preprint on ArXiv AND ReseachGate?

Tags: publications, arxiv, preprint, social-media

Since I recently published my first ever paper, I was creating some accounts for various social networks and preprint servers. I have to say, I am a little bit confused by ReseachGate: If I have already uploaded a paper to arXiv and I also want it to be on ResearchGate, do I have to upload it separately on ReseachGate (I am not able to find any way to crosslink my arXiv paper on ResearchGate)?

And what if my preprint gets published later on? Is it then still "legal" that the paper is available for everyone on ResearchGate, or do I have to be careful in order not to run into any copyright problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [Sherpa Romeo database](https://v2.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/) to see if the publisher and/or journal accepts papers that have been posted online as a preprint/working paper.

Most publishers and journals do not consider preprints, working papers, or conference presentations as 'publications' but it ultimately differs from field to field (especially for fields where conferences are the mainstream ways to publish).

Regarding ResearchGate, arxiv (and its associated servers) papers are usually automatically detected and put on your profile by ResearchGate after a few days. If not, then you should be able to upload it onto ResearchGate manually as a preprint and include the arxiv doi in there, at which point other scholarly search engines (e.g., Google Scholar) will detect both.

Even after you get your published, your publisher/journal may be okay with you posting the author-accepted version of the paper on ResearchGate or Arxiv granted that you've also posted a link to the published, copyedited version. But again, check the Sherpa Romeo database to confirm.